# Golang Unit Test Mock method of nested struct

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking

I want to mock a method of a nested struct. I have tried to define an interface and make the Mock implement it, but I could not get it working.

This is the struct I want to test:

```
type OuterThing struct {
    innerThing *InnerThing
}

func (a *OuterThing) doLotsOfStuff() {
    println("i am doing")
    u, err := a.innerThing.DoStuff("lots of stuff")
    if err != nil {
        println("ran into an error, also doing some logic")
    }
    println("and more", u)
}
```

The nested struct, of which I want to mock its `DoStuff()` function, looks like this:

```
type InnerThing struct {
    name string
}

func (b *InnerThing) DoStuff(x string) (uint64, error) {
    println("i want to mock this method")
    return 0, nil
}
```

*Little side twist: I can not change the code of these structs and their methods.*

To make my point a bit more clear i have written this test:

```
func TestDoLotsOfStuff(t *testing.T) {
    testCases := []struct {
        name            string
        structUnderTest *OuterThing
    }{
        {
            name: "happy case",
            structUnderTest: &OuterThing{
                innerThing: &InnerThing{name: "I am the inner thing."},
            },
        },
        {
            name: "error case",
            structUnderTest: &OuterThing{
                innerThing: &InnerThing{name: "i should be a mock with a mocked DoStuff function"},
            },
        },
    }

    for _, testCase := range testCases {
        t.Run(testCase.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            testCase.structUnderTest.doLotsOfStuff()
            // assertions
        })
    }
}
```

I am quite familiar with Java and Mockito and this would be a pretty trivial task. I know Go has lots of differences with its implicit interfaces and no classes et cetera, but is this really such an uncommon usecase?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using an Interface and Dependency Injection.
Let's say, you have an Interface called `Inner` that contains the `DoStuff()` method. The `OuterThing` struct should contain this Interface instead of the struct `InnerThing`. Now, you can use dependency injection to pass the `Inner` Interface to this `OuterThing` struct.

```golang
type Inner interface {
    DoStuff(string) (uint64, error)
}

type OuterThing struct {
    innerThing Inner
}

func NewOuterThing(in Inner) *OuterThing {
    return &OuterThing{
        innerThing: in,
    }
}
```

Now, in the test, you can create the `mockInnerThing` struct and implement the mock `DoStuff()` method and pass the `mockInnerThing` to the `OuterThing` struct.

```golang
type MockInnerThing struct {
    name string
}

func NewMockInnerThing(name string) *MockInnerThing {
    return &MockInnerThing{
        name: name,
    }
}

func (b *MockInnerThing) DoStuff(x string) (uint64, error) {
    println("Mock!")
    return 0, nil
}
```

```golang
func TestDoLotsOfStuff(t *testing.T) {
    mit := NewMockInnerThing("Test")
    ot := NewOuterThing(mit)
    ot.doLotsOfStuff()
}
```

Comment: I get a compile-time error: Unresolved reference 'DoStuff' inside the `doLotsOfStuff()` method.

Comment: can you show me the code?

Comment: Ok, I checked the pointers again and the compile time error is gone. But I had to change the source code of the structs i did not want to. Thanks anyways